# Wordpress site misbehaves from redirect URL only

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect

My wordpress site, askamiga.ultimateamiga.co.uk is working fine. But since I had the domain www.askamiga.com redirect to it, the login button does nothing even though on hover it shows a URL.

The redirect was achieved by the domain provider (not the hosting provider) and they used a frame within an index.html to achieve the redirect.

Is it possible to make this work without using htaccess (which I don't understand)?

So to reiterate, the redirect itself seems fine. But *some* of the links (such as login) don't work, despite showing a valid URL on hover.

Comment: Using htaccess is pretty easy in this case. Just a single line `Redirect 301 / http://askamiga.ultimateamiga.co.uk` is enough.

Comment: Thanks. But when the user types in www.askamiga.com, I want that to stay in the address bar even though it's the other site that gets loaded. From what I'm reading 301 is a standard (not masked) redirect that encourages search engines to point people away from the URL (www.askamiga.com).